# Dual citizenship - Mexican/American - customs on leaving Mexico

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration

My son was born in Mexico and has dual citizenship. He has the CRBA and Mexican birth certificate also an American passport. Will he have to pay customs to leave Mexico? He’s been here for 2 years and entered on American passport

Comment: He also does not have a mexican pssport can i just use his american passport to fly?

Comment: Does anyone have to pay customs to leave Mexico?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate by the same OP to a yet unanswered question.